# JavaFX8 - referencing FXML objects from a different thread

Tags: java, concurrency, javafx, javafx-8, fxml

So I have a JavaFX8 app, and I am trying to create scheduled thread that changes a GUI element on each iteration. I am using ScheduledExecutorService, however if any code in the run() method references an FXML object, it dies without any errors.

This code resides in the Controller for my main FXML window. fxmlLabel is declared as `@FXML private Label fxmlLabel;`

This code works, and correctly prints "Hello World!" every second.

```
Runnable task = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
    }
};
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

This code prints "Hello World!" once, then nothing happens.

```
Runnable task = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
        fxmlLabel.setText("Bye world!");
        System.out.println("Hello again!");
    }
};
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: You can't change the state of a "live" UI component from a background thread. In Java 8 this should give you an exception. Use `Platform.runLater()`, or use the `javafx.concurrent` API.

Comment: @James_D I don't get an exception. Could you give me an example? I thought I was using `javafx.concurrent` EDIT: Whoops I mixed it up with java.util.concurrent.

Comment: You're using java.util.concurrent, but not javafx.concurrent. I'll post an example (or two).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't change the state of a UI element that is part of a displayed scene graph from a background thread. In Java 8, this throws an exception. In earlier versions of JavaFX, it may throw an exception or may fail silently.

To fix this, either wrap the calls that update the scene graph in `Platform.runLater(...)`:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class UpdateLabelRegularly extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Label label = new Label();
        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().add(label);
        ScheduledExecutorService exec = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5, r -> {
           Thread t = new Thread(r);
           t.setDaemon(true);
           return t ;
        });
        AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger();
        Runnable task = () -> {
            System.out.println("Hello world!");
            Platform.runLater(() -> label.setText("Count: "+count.incrementAndGet()));
            System.out.println("Hello again");
        };
        exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 250, 75);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Or use the [`javafx.concurrent.ScheduledService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/ScheduledService.html) class:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.ScheduledService;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class UpdateLabelRegularly extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Label label = new Label();
        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().add(label);
        AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger();
        ScheduledService<String> service = new ScheduledService<String>() {
            @Override
            protected Task<String> createTask() {
                Task<String> task = new Task<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String call() {
                        return "Count: "+count.incrementAndGet();
                    }
                };
                return task ;
            }
        };
        service.setOnSucceeded(event -> label.setText(service.getValue()));
        service.setDelay(Duration.seconds(1));
        service.setPeriod(Duration.seconds(1));
        service.start();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 250, 75);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

In general the second approach is better (imho) as it gives a nice separation between the logic of the task and the update of the UI on completion. Refer to the [Javadocs for `Task`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) and [`ScheduledService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/ScheduledService.html) for lots more examples.

**One more update:**
Just for completeness, here's a version using a `ScheduledExecutorService` and the `javafx.concurrent` API, just in case there's some reason you're forced to do it this way:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class UpdateLabelRegularly extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Label label = new Label();
        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().add(label);
        AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger();
        ScheduledExecutorService exec = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5, r -> {
            Thread t = new Thread(r);
            t.setDaemon(true);
            return t ;
        });
        exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
            Task<String> task = new Task<String>() {
                @Override
                public String call() {
                    return "Count: "+count.incrementAndGet();
                }
            };
            task.setOnSucceeded(event -> label.setText(task.getValue()));
            task.run();
        }, 1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 250, 75);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works in the fact it updates the label, however it only executes once (displays Count: 1 and never changes).

Comment: It runs fine for me... updates every second (both versions). Are you running the exact code I posted?

Comment: Yes, I created a new project, copied and pasted your code (added package at the top) and clicked run (NetBeans). I'm using the second example by the way.

Comment: Ah, yeah... the second one doesn't work because you can't execute a `Task` multiple times. Sorry: must have made a mistake testing it. Let me fix it...

Comment: Fixed, using a `ScheduledService` instead.